# "Predictive dependence" between two variables

Tags: mathematical-statistics, independence, accuracy, information-theory, conditional-independence

Given two random variables $X$ and $Y$, it is natural to use the conditional entropy $H[Y|X]$ to quantify the extent to which knowing $X$ decreases the uncertainty about $Y$. However, consider the case where I am not interested in whether $X$ decreases the uncertainty about $Y$: I only want to quantify whether knowing $X$ allows me to predict $Y$ **with an above-majority accuracy**. Is there a notion of "predictive dependence" that captures this?

**Example**: Consider a distribution over binary $Y,X$ with the marginals $P[Y=1]=0.75$,  $P[X=1]=0.55$ and the conditionals $P[Y=1|X=1] = 0.818$, $P[Y=1|X=0]=0.666$. Notice that $Y=1$ is the majority value of $Y$ over (1) the entire population (2) the cases where $X=0$ (3) the cases where $X=1$. So knowing $X$ doesn't help me in predicting $Y$ above the majority accuracy of $75\%$, even though $H[Y|X]$ is lower than $H[Y]$.

**What does majority accuracy mean?** the majority accuracy of a variable $Z$ is defined as $max_{z \in Z} {P[Z=z]}$. For instance, if $Z$ is a binary variable with $P[Z=1]=0.75$ and $P[Z=0]=0.25$, its majority accuracy is 75% (A predictor that always guesses the value of $Z=1$ will be correct in $75\%$ of the cases). The majority accuracy is the highest accuracy that a constant predictor can get.

Comment: Please tell us what "above-majority accuracy" means and how it is measured in general.

Comment: I added a clarification in the body of the question.

Comment: It sounds like another name for the *mode* of a discrete variable.  That's not going to be terribly meaningful for non-discrete variables.  It would help, then, to specify more narrowly the kinds of random variables you are interested in.

Comment: I am interested specifically in discrete variables.